# How can I perform multi channel DCT in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, transform, dct

I want to replace average pooling with dc component of dct transform, But I couldn't find a function that replace that with avgpooing2d in pytorch.
I find dct package in following link:
https://github.com/zh217/torch-dct
but when I try dct_2d[0, 0, :] it doesn't operate the same way as avgpooling, and for example for a 7 7 3042 tensor it outputs a 49 tensor! (but the dimensional must be 1 1 3042)

Comment: what is the difference between the ["DC component"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/12972/7146) and the average?

Comment: DCT is reversible but avgpooling is not reversible transform

Comment: If you take all DCT coefficients, then DCT is invertible, but if you take only one coefficient (DC or other) then you cannot recover the original signal from it.

Comment: So Is there a reversible pooling?

Comment: a pooling operation is a **sampling** operation: you output fewer values than inputs. How do you propose to recover the lost information?

Comment: In flow based architecture for known networks like ResNet I have seen some examples of reversible downsampling

Comment: there is "max unpooling" where you store the index of the max element and use it to "un-pool" the layer. But this is not a reversible mapping. If you increase the channel dimension to compensate for the loss of spatial information, then you can, theoretically, have invertible pooling

Comment: Thanks. You are right.